# ServiceConnect with Instagram

Tags: social-media, api

WRI has told me they don't support Instagram anymore due to their change in privacy policy. Instagram still remains in `$Services`.

I came across this and was wondering if there is an easier way to connect manually now?

[Connecting Instagram to WM: ServiceConnect not working](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149351/connecting-instagram-to-wm-serviceconnect-not-working)

Edit: is there a new updated paclet, as @b3m2a1 suggested?

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of the question you linked to

Comment: You can post a comment on @b3m2a1's posted answer there.

Comment: I've previously commented on his post and was told to start a new question.

Comment: You didn't post a "comment" on @b3m2a1's post. You posted an "answer" to the question, but your post wasn't an answer. So you got a boilerplate response from the SE delete menu. Perhaps the comment wasn't the best choice, since it appears this is not really a new question.